# Generic method that checks entity existence in Core Data database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I want to write generic method that checks if a given entity is in a Core Data database. I would like to have one method that works for all entities. I came up with something like this:

```
-(BOOL)checkIfExistsEntity:(NSString *)entityName withFieldName:(NSString *)fieldName andFieldValue:(NSString *)value{

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext  = [(FGuideAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *selectEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                                    entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:selectEntityDescription];

    NSPredicate *whereForFetch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ = %@",fieldName, value];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:whereForFetch];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (array != nil && [array count] > 0){
        return YES;
    }else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

However it looks like the string `@"%@ = %@"` in the predicate I wrote is not parsed properly. Is there any way to implement described functionality without hardcoding entities properties in a predicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out dynamic property names in the link below. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Instead of `%@`, using `%K` should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you need == not = (I think....)

Comment: It looks like that in NSPredicate we use SQL convention when it comes to equal sign, so = should be used (strangely, Core Data does not complain about ==, so maybe they are interchangable?)

Comment: I always use the ==, as per Apple docs... NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"employeeID == %@", anID];
 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

Comment: I've checked @"%@ == %@" does not work. If, in the same code I am insterting @"fieldName == %@" the method works.

Comment: Have a look at NSExpression... check the Creating Predicates In Code in... http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the countForFetchRequest method.